# C# Local Subreport not found

Tags: c#, sql-server-express, subreport, localreport

I am working on a Winforms app that must run entirely locally - when in use the computer will not be on any network. It is interfacing with a local SQL Server Express database.

I have a report `localReport_SelectedSwitchList.rdlc` that references, and passes a parameter to, a subreport (`localReport_SelectedWayBills.rdlc`).

The main report renders correctly but the subreport returns an error:

[image: SwitchList Main Report]

The subreport name has been entered correctly, though it had to be typed because no pull-down list or dialog option is offered.

[image: Definition of the Subreport]

I have tried variations: with extension/without extension, with a '.' in front. A  path with backslashes (\) will not compile.  Note that the error message includes the correct path and name.

I have found other similar questions posted going back many years but none have been resolved.

Comment: ignore rdlc subreport error message. just check everything one by one.are you sure data type of parameter are correct in subreport ?

Comment: And send data to subreport in LocalReport_SubreportProcessing event.

Comment: @TaiwanHotDog can you please provide an example (c# preferred) of the code used in the LocalReport_SubreportProcessing event.  Also, I have created a skeleton event handler but it is not being invoked.

Comment: [dropbox example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/24fwxrgt8qoegf1/WinReportTest.7z?dl=0)